Would it be a bad idea to set sources.list and sources.list.d only root permissions?
I need to add an repository that requires OAuth 2.0 authentication so I've got to pass it an access token. One of idea is to write it as a query parameter or as Basic Auth password in /etc/apt/sources.list file:
deb http://oauthrepourl.com?accesstoken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9 suite classic

OR

deb http://somelogin:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9@oauthrepourl.com suite classic

But I guess it would be unsecure to keep an access token there because sources.list and sources.list.d files are accessible to read for all users:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2852 апр 24 13:41 sources.list
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 сен 25 10:17 sources.list.d

Would it be a bad idea to make sources.list and sources.list.d content only accessible for root user (-rwx------)? You can use apt anyway as a root (as it has to be though) and usual users would not be able to stole the access token from these files.
P.S. I know there's an file /etc/apt/auth.conf that would help to keep it in secret but it seems my distribution's apt is too old and does not support it.

If the tokens need to be secure, your first step should be using HTTPS, not HTTP. With a regular HTTP URL the whole URL is visible to anybody who can sniff network traffic (which includes any routers between you and the actual repo servers (including your ISP and the repo server’s ISP if you’re going over the internet), and probably anybody else on the network), including the auth token. There is also zero reason these days to be using plain HTTP for APT repos unless you absolutely have to use a transparent proxy to access them or the repos themselves don’t provide HTTPS.

Minor when compared to the glaring non-TLS connection issue, but if you can choose, choose basic auth; that way username and password will be sent in a header, which is less likely to be logged server-side (the query string often is).

I think it wouldn’t be a bad idea.
Making /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d accessible only to root doesn’t break anything important. In particular, apt update and apt upgrade etc. need to run as root and don’t drop privileges when accessing those files, so they work fine with this setup.
The only operations that no longer work are apt subcommands run as non-root and requiring access to the repository configuration, for example apt policy (which doesn’t technically fail, but doesn’t show any repository information). Some commands still work but give warnings about sources.list, for example apt search.
Note that since you’re not using TLS to connect to your repositories, anyone that can sniff the network traffic will be able to see the credentials.
